# How to disable screensaver on Qt Android App

Tags: android, c++, qt, screensaver

I am using Qt on Android and I would like to disable the screen turning off / screensaver turning on.

I am not using QtQuick / QML, only C++. The Qt version is 5.8

**edit:** I forgot to mention that I use Qt Creator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual [source](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57625/solved-keep-android-5-screen-on)

You need to add "QT += androidextras" to the .pro file

```
#include <QtAndroidExtras/QAndroidJniEnvironment>
#include <QtAndroidExtras/QtAndroidExtras>

QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if (activity.isValid()) {
    QAndroidJniObject window = activity.callObjectMethod("getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");
    if (window.isValid()) {
        const int FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON = 128;
        window.callMethod<void>("addFlags", "(I)V", FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}

//Clear any possible pending exceptions.
QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
    env->ExceptionClear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. There just needs to be exception handling, otherwise it crashes. I added it to your answer.